# Create a folder after uploading and saving a document

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want after downloading a file that it is automatically put in "My iphone" with a folder created beforehand ( for example "CreateFolder")
Currently I have done this following code but it displays the choice to the user if they want to save it or whatever. What i don't want
My code :

```
let urlString = body;

    let url = URL(string: urlString);

    // Récupération du nom du fichier complet + que l'extension + que le nom

    let fileName = String((url!.lastPathComponent)) as String;

    let fileExt  = String((url!.pathExtension)) as String

    let fileNameWithoutExt : String = String(fileName.prefix(fileName.count - (fileExt.count+1)));



    // Create destination URL

    // Création du chemin (système) par défaut ( file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6CD1C41B-8D24-466B-A32B-2EC26FE1E8C6/Documents/)

    let documentsUrl:URL =  (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL?)!;

    var destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName)");

    

    // Vérification présence fichier si il existe on rajoute un (1) etc..

    var counter = 0;

    var newFileName : String!;

    

    while FileManager().fileExists(atPath: destinationFileUrl.path) {

        counter += 1;

        newFileName =  "\(fileNameWithoutExt)_\(counter).\(fileExt)";

        destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(newFileName);

       }

    //Create URL to the source file you want to download

    // Création pour le lancement du téléchargement

    let fileURL = URL(string: urlString);

    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default;

    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig);

    let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!);

    // Ici commence le téléchargement

    let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in

        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {

            // Success

            if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {

                print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")

            }

            do {

                // Cette partie permet de copier le fichier stocké ( système Apple ) à l'endroit voulu

                // avec le nouveau du fichier si déjà présent

                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl);

                do {

                    //Show UIActivityViewController to save the downloaded file

                    // Partie qui permet d'afficher le "popup" pour savoir ce que l'on souhaite faire avec le document téléchargé ( envoyer, enregistrer etc...)

                    // Récupération de tous les fichiers dans le chemin système

                    let contents  = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles);

                    // La boucle permet de parcourir tous les fichiers stocké dans le chemin système d'Apple

                    // Arriver au dernier ( donc celui téléchargé )

                   for indexx in 0..<contents.count {

                       if contents[indexx].lastPathComponent == destinationFileUrl.lastPathComponent {

                        // Ceci met en fil d'attente les éléments et affiche le popup quand la boucle est terminée

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            // Affiche le popup de ce que l'on souhaite faire

                            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [contents[indexx]], applicationActivities: nil);

                            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);

                        }

                       }

                   }

                }

                catch (let err) {

                    print("error: \(err)");

                }

            } catch (let writeError) {

                print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)");

            }

        } else {

            print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")");

        }

    }

    task.resume();
```

This is what I would like :
[image]

Is it possible to create a folder and put the downloaded file without selecting the destination by the user?
Thanking you in advance

Comment: There is not a solution with FileManager to create a folder in "On my Iphone" and insert the downloaded file in this folder?

Comment: No. You can share your _whole_ Documents folder into On My IPhone. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/204/ You cannot arbitrarily write directly into On My iPhone.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Comment: Sorry I don't know that @Yunnosch

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for those who are looking to have their file To do this in your Info.plist file add the following 2 keys

- Application Supports Itunes file sharing
- Supports opening documents in place

With my code, you can comment out DispatchQueue.main.async (because useless now) and you will see your files in "In My Iphone"

[image]
Thank you very much to @matt

Answer (score -2):

With your document open, click File > Save As.
Under Save As, select where you want to create your new folder.
In the Save As dialog box that opens, click New Folder.
Type the name of your new folder, and press Enter.
Click Save.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question.

Comment: The OP is asking how they can make their iOS app save into the user's "My iPhone" directory, not how to save files into folders on their Mac.